# Object conversion in equal namespaces / different projects

Tags: c#

How to convert an object (eg MMM.CC) but in the same object that is in another project / namespace (eg XXX.CC)?

Both objects (DC) are the same. A (MMM.CC) is the DLL and the other (XXX.CC) is a MMM.CC of Reference instantiated in another project (WEB SERVICE)

I tried as follows:

IN DLL I make a call to another project (WEB SERVICE which has references of own DLL if MMM.CC) and returns an object similar to MMM.CC

```
XXX.CC xc = new XXX.CC(); // create an instance of webservice.
MMM.CC mc = new MMM.CC (); // create an instance of the dll.
xc.Return_object_XXXCC (); // WebMethod that returns an object of type XXX.CC.MMM.CC.
mc = xc;
```

OR :

```
XXX.CC xc = new XXX.CC(); // create an instance of webservice.
MMM.CC mc = new MMM.CC (); // create an instance of the dll.
mc = xc.Return_object_XXXCC (); // WebMethod that returns an object of type XXX.CC.MMM.CC.
```

OR :

```
XXX.CC xc = new XXX.CC(); // create an instance of webservice.
MMM.CC mc = new MMM.CC (); // create an instance of the dll.
mc = (MMM.CC)xc.Return_object_XXXCC (); // WebMethod that returns an object of type XXX.CC.MMM.CC.
```

I do not know if I'm being clear, but both the DLL and in WEBSERVICE, both CC objects are the same, but because they are in different namespaces are giving conversion error.

Even tried:

```
mc = (MMM.CC) xc;
```

But does not convert.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.  .NET doesn't support this kind of typecasting.

You'll need to map one to the other, copying the state of the XXX.CC instance into the MMM.CC instance.

There are libraries that can make this easy and automatic, but that's often overkill.

Answer (score 0):

> Both objects (DC) are the same

No, the *fully qualified type name* is not the same because namespaces are different, so technically both objects have a **different type**.

So you won't be able to "just cast them", you'll have to write a method that is able to manually convert one type into the other type.